# How to disable background slideshow and make this setting stick

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, slideshow

My windows 10 pc has two monitors, and I managed to install a different background wallpaper for each. However, after a while, the backgrounds appear on the wrong monitor. I tried to turn off `slideshow` in Personalize, Background, but this setting does not stick. When I return to that settings screen, slideshow is still set. Consequently, the wallpapers will not stay on their intended monitor.

Please help

Comment: How did you install a different background wallpaper for each monitor?

Comment: If you're *not* an Administrator, try logging as such and make the changes. There is also a Windows 10 defect, see https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-fix-desktop-and-lock-screen-background-slideshow-reset-to-picture/ for workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, DrMoishe Pippik, for the link to the Windows bug. Except that is the reverse problem, of how to enable slideshow.

In my case, our clever system admin noted that having two pictures selected, Windows "thinks" about a slideshow, logically.

As a programmer myself, this would make sense. Just think about it. Someone made a nice settings app for slideshows with all kinds of nifty features, and then thought, well, if you don't want a slideshow, you just install only one (1) picture. So the option for "picture" is just an extra menu option, without any extra software behind it.

@harrymc How did I install a different background wallpaper for each monitor? Well, the hard way is to use the Settings, Background app, which may or may not have a feature for this. The easy way, which I found on some windows forum, is to use File Explorer, by going to the folder with your wallpapers, select two pictures using the control key, go to the context menu with the right mouse button, select "Set as desktop background". That simple.

In most cases, this does not work exactly as you wished, one or both monitors can show the wrong image. Then, just right-click on a free place on one of the monitors, i.e., on one of the wallpapers, and select "Next desktop background".

However, this last tip also shows that "slideshow" is enabled. Which proves the theory of my system admin. The bottom line is that:

`You cannot select a different wallpaper on each monitor and make this stick.`

What you CAN do is set the slideshow interval to the maximum value of one day, to minimize the pain of having to deal with this Windows limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new folder with just the pics you want to display for each monitor. I have two monitors, so I created a folder with just two pics. So while the rotation of pics still happens depending on your time interval, it'll only be for the pics in that folder. I set mine to change once a day, but it's only two pics, so they just switch monitors.

Comment: Welcome Emily to this forum! Your answer is generally useful, +1, but in my case, the monitors were different size, and even different aspect ratio. The modern monitor was UDH 16:9, and the second an older 4:3 monitor. Then, rotation causes black bars or distortion. Hence my problem.